# Invalid log level Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

First time i saw this error, I tried `chmod -R 777 storage` but nothing changed.

Anyone know how to fix this error ? also i tried `composer update`

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Check your config or .env file settings your log level's should be from this array :

```
protected $levels = [
        'debug'     => MonologLogger::DEBUG,
        'info'      => MonologLogger::INFO,
        'notice'    => MonologLogger::NOTICE,
        'warning'   => MonologLogger::WARNING,
        'error'     => MonologLogger::ERROR,
        'critical'  => MonologLogger::CRITICAL,
        'alert'     => MonologLogger::ALERT,
        'emergency' => MonologLogger::EMERGENCY,
    ];
```

So in .env file :

```
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

Or other you want.

If it will be blank or selected wrong then you will may get this error.